# Некорректная запись данных из Option в БД

Tags: php, form, mariadb, запись

Стоит задача сделать запись настроек из формы, где в option человек будет указывать модель:

```
     <select class="form-control" name="model">
     <option value="1">Model One</option>
     <option value="2">Model Free</option>
     <option value="3">Model Five</option>
     </select>
```

У каждой модели есть свой номер value (1/2/3)
Далее я получаю эти данные через POST и преобразую в текст:

```
   $type = $data['model'];
   if($type = 1) {
     $num = 'Model "HP" G';
   }
   if($type = 2) {
     $num = 'Model "HP" S';
   }
   if($type = 3) {
     $num = 'Model "HP" X';
   }
```

После произвожу запись данных в базу данных (использую redbeanphp):

```
$evsadd->name = $num;
```

После выбора модели и отправки всего этого на сервер, в БД все время записывается вариант с value = 3 (Model "HP" X). В чем ошибка? Буду рад помощи!

Comment: `if( $type = 1 ) ` это не сравнивание. вот это `==`, потому и получаете `value = 3`

Comment: Это действительно помогло, Спасибо Огромное!